# In Android how to pass ListAdapter values to onItemClick?

Tags: android, listview

I've got a functioning search interface on my app. Now I'm trying to make each search result list item clickable and display in a new activity. I've got them clickable, but I can't figure out how to pass the `ListAdapter` values (records) into the `onItemClick` method.

Here's my code so far:

```
private void showResults(String query) {
    Cursor cursor = DBHelper.searchDB(query);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] searchFrom = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_MAKE,
            DBAdapter.KEY_YEAR, DBAdapter.KEY_MAKE,
            DBAdapter.KEY_MODEL };
    int[] displayHere = new int[] { R.id.rDateTV, R.id.rYearTV,
            R.id.rMakeTV, R.id.rModelTV };

    final SimpleCursorAdapter records = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.record_2, cursor, searchFrom, displayHere);

    setListAdapter(records);
    DBHelper.close();

    // --- Click on list item ---


    ListView clickList = getListView(); 
    clickList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)        {
            //--- here's the problem: how do I pass the ListAdapter values into onItemClick. the below doesn't like .getText()
            String sYear = (view.findViewById(R.id.rYearTV)).getText().toString();
            String sMake = (view.findViewById(R.id.rMakeTV)).getText().toString();
            String sModel = (view.findViewById(R.id.rModelTV)).getText().toString();

            // -- then pass these strings to an intent to launch a new activity




        } 
    });


    // --- END click on list item ----

}
```

Any ideas? I'm a rookie here, so if you could show me the code, that would be AWSOME!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `OnItemClickListener.onItemClick` call `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`. That method returns cursor which is set to the given position. Then get your data from that cursor. Don't close cursor inside `OnItemClickListener.onItemClick`.

for example:

```
ListView clickList = getListView(); 
    clickList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)        {
            Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
            String sMake = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_MAKE));//get data from cursor

           ...
        } 
    });
```